# Shipping Table Rate issue

Tags: magento2, shipping

I'm trying to use table rates, I have 3 rates:

1. for items between 0 and 150 lbs: $19.99
2. for items between 150 and 155 lbs: $79.99
3. for items over 155 lbs: $99.99

On top of those I want to offer free shipping for all items over $150 but one brand, let's say "Tesla", so I've created a cart promotion rule, where I specified cart price to be over $150 and the brand IS NOT Tesla.

All Tesla items are somewhere between 150 and 155 lbs.

Everything works fine if the customer adds to cart a Tesla item first, the shipping price is $79.99.

However if the customer is adding to cart a product with free shipping, and after that is adding a Tesla item, the shipping price is $19.99, which is wrong, it should be either $79.99 either $99.99.

Any idea why is this happening?

I'm using Magento 2.1.3  CE on Centos 7 with php 7.0.14

Answer (score 0):

would add weight like this, and check wither its working or not

```
for items between 0 and 149.99 lbs: $19.99

for items between 150 and 154.99 lbs: $79.99

for items over 155 lbs: $99.99
```

Also check the "Free shipping" option in cart price rule there are three options of free shipping you need to check which one to work